# Error when add .jar file in Classpath

Tags: android

Hi.
I created a project which can send email using JavaMail. But when I add the .jar file in my classpath, I get the following error message. I don't know which error is this. Because it only show the "your project contain error" message.

Please provide me some answer.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? if yes, there's error view (not the console) somewhere containing detailed descriptions

Comment: Removing the jar shows no errors?

Comment: In Eclipse try Window - Show View - Problems

Comment: I use Eclipse..But when i remove jar file it doesn't show any error.and it's not showing anything in "Error Log".

Comment: Is your jar compiled with same java version as the project's compiler version?

Comment: @sans481 It's necessary to compile the jar file?

Comment: You need not to compile. But if your jar was compiled using a different java version, it might cause problem. Is your jar showing some red marks on it?

Comment: No red mark not shown on jar file but show on project name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely the jar is using classes that Dalvik does not implement. If you're using a jar compiled for Java SE it's possible.

Comment: I have already jar file. when i try to compile it using JavaSe,it show error. How i implement this file in dalvik? Thanks

Comment: It show the error "invalid zip file"! how to solve this problem?